# Polymorphic null coalescing operator

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, polymorphism, operators

Consider

```
interface IResult {}
class Result : IResult {}
class Results : IResult {}

class Producer {
    private Results results;
    IResult DoSomething() {
        return results ?? new Result();
    }
}
```

this fails with the compiler error

```
Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type `Result` and `Results`
```

For me, this is unexpected behavior. Thinking about it, the .NET framework probably creates an intermediate variable of type `Results` (the left operand). The right operand `Result` is of different type and as such will spawn a type conversion error. Is this assumption correct?

If yes, why won't csc detect the intermediate variable is of type `IResult`?

So I changed the code to look like

```
return results == null ? new Result() : results;
```

yet this code errs on

```
There is no explicit conversion between `Result` and `Results`
```

Why? I do not expect this, since both instances conform to IResult.

Comment: The type of the left operand is `Results`, not `IResult`. You need to cast to get the compiler to understand this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it is expected. Because `Result` and `Results` are not the same class they just implement a common interface but they are not convertible to each other, that's why you are getting the error.

> If yes, why won't csc detect the intermediate variable is of type IResult?

This would cause an ambiguity. What would happen if your types implements more than one common interface, say `IFoo`. Then compiler should pick `IResult` or `IFoo` ? You can say it should choose the `IResult` because of the return type but what should happen it this is not a return statement, this might be simple assignment for example.. So in short, `C#` compiler doesn't make assumptions on types.

This is also stated in `C# Specification` in  `7.13 The null coalescing operator`

> The type of the expression `a ?? b` depends on which implicit conversions are available on the operands.In order of preference, the type of `a ?? b` is `A0`, `A`, or `B`, where `A` is the type of `a` (provided that a has a type), `B` is the type of `b` (provided that b has a type), and A0 is the underlying type of A if A is a nullable type, or A otherwise.  Specifically, `a ?? b` is processed as follows:
>
> - [...] if `A` exists and an implicit conversion exists from `b` to `A`, the result type is `A`
> - [...] if `b` has a type `B` and an implicit conversion exists from `a` to `B`, the result type is B.
> - Otherwise, `a` and `b` are *incompatible,* and a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: This could be worded better - if `Result` and `Results` were both being referred to by their respective types then, yes, they are not compatible types. However, they both implement a common interface which does make them compatible if the objects are referred to by the interface type, rather than the implementing types. Saying they are not "compatible types" is misleading. (EDIT: this is regarding to your original post, prior to the edits

Comment: You have both the *complete* and *correct* answer, so I marked this as answer.

Comment: C# might add a clause where return type inference may be applied in this case.

Answer (score 7):

Because this:

```
return results ?? new Result();
```

Actually it tries to cast the value of the last parameter to the same type as the first. The compiler thinks this is the type you need. It doesn't use the type of the variable you are assigning it to.

You need an implicit cast. Cast it to `IResult` and you will be fine:

```
return (IResult)results ?? new Result();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Alternate syntax: return (results as IResult) ?? new Result();

Comment: _It doesn't use the type of the variable you are assigning it to._ this is not actually related to return type. even if you change return type to `Result` or `Results` this expression still invalid: `results ?? new Result();`

Comment: As you explained too, you *might* expect that it does. But it clearly doesn't.

Comment: FYI I downvoted you because according to specification you are wrong. The compiler doesn't use the type of first operand. For example this compiles too: `return results ?? ((IResult)new Result());`

Comment: @Selman22: Thanks for letting me know. You are right about that. Can you verify the update?